# Reliable udp using tcp retransmit

Tags: python, c++

I am client receiver of UDP multicast data sent by Sender server (Stock Exchange data). I am continuously receiving udp multicast packet flow sequentially numbered 1 to approximately 35,000,000 sent uniformly over a period of 6 hours . I need to ensure *all* packets upto say N are received before the set of N packets is periodically processed after every say ~ 256 packets. i.e. I need reliable UDP.

Reliable UDP is mimicked using TCP retransmit. If any udp packet(s) is lost/not received, it is requested by using tcp protocol by specifying the desired missing packet range (starting number, ending number).
Sender keeps record of *all* the packets (stock exchange data) it has sent via UDP multicast so far. So Sender will resend by TCP only those packets numbers that the receiver specifically requests for via TCP. This is how UDP reliability is achieved by receiver. The UDP drop ratio is very small (less than 0.001%) except when starting the UDP multicast in the middle of the day, in which case all previously sent UDP packets from 1 to some N will need to be resent on TCP, while live transmission of UDP multicast data packet number N+1 onward is being received.) I can't request Sender (Stock Exchange) to change its protocol--it is fixed.

What is the efficient algorithm to implement this in terms of CPU?
The issue is speed BigOh. I can make a naive algorithm using several nested loops and methods, but it not necessarily the best.

I am thinking of maintaining a number N which confirms I have received UDP 
 packets 1 through N, and any packet no. M which is not the next expected packet no. N+1 will be buffered, for say 256 packets, and then TCP will be used to request the missing numbers. Then normal UDP reception resumes over from the last confirmed received number after TCP request is filled.

Example: 
Suppose UDP packets received by receiver are in the following sequence {1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10 ...}
After packet No. 3, the next packet is No. 6. Packets 4 through 5 are missing. 
So the missing packets {4,5} are requested using TCP request({4 through 5}), and  {6,7,8,9,10} are buffered. There is enough space on the 10GBaseT LAN card for buffering 35,000,000 packets. 
So: receive  UDP {1,2,3}, refill by TCP request {4,5}, continue receive UDP {6,7,8,9,10, ...}

Comment: Take a look at RTP protocol.

Comment: Clarifying: So no UDP retransmit?  Lost packets are sent later via TCP?

Comment: Yes, there is no udp retransmit. The missing number(s) are requested by using tcp. This is live tick by tick data from stock exchange. I need reliability on packets 1 through N.

Comment: "Efficient algorithm" - I fail to see what quantity you're trying to optimize. Bandwidth, latency, CPU, RAM?

Comment: I fail to see what the actual question is. Just implement your protocol.

Comment: Sender should keep some packets (the number of packets depends and you will need to experiment probably) in memory and just resend it via the same udp multicast on request, which would be received by udp as well. You might also fill us with some additional data - for example how important it is for a job to receive all udp packets (tcp connection can fail as well!)?

Comment: Sender (Stock Exchange) keeps **all** the packets it has sent via UDP multicast. It becomes historical data. The live generated data is sent by UDP, whereas historical data is sent by TCP only if receiver specifically requests for the historical/missing data.

Answer (score 1):

I assume since you are using multicast that there are going to be multiple receivers of this data?  (Because if not, you'd probably be using unicast instead)

Therefore, if the receivers are going to have the option of requesting TCP retransmission of packets they didn't get, that means that the transmitting program will need to keep a copy of recently-sent UDP packets in memory, so that when it receives a retransmit-request, it will have the requested data available to retransmit.  Assuming you're stamping each packet with a unique ID, it can store this data in a `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` or similar for quick lookup.

The real question becomes, how much of this old-packet data should the transmitter retain?  ideally it would retain all of it, because you never know how much a given receiver might have missed and might want to request; but that would require infinite memory so that's not a realistic option.  Probably the best you can do is decide how much RAM you're willing to tie up for this purpose, and keep a count of the total number of bytes you have in your table, and when it reaches the limit, start dropping the oldest packets from the table in order to keep its size under the limit.

I wrote an [open-source library](https://jfriesne.github.io/zg_choir_docs/index.html) that uses essentially the technique you describe (multicast UDP + TCP-retransmit-to-recover-from-packet-loss) to synchronize databases across multiple hosts as quickly as possible; some things I learned while implementing it include:

- If/when you can, pack your data-messages together into larger packets, up to the MTU of the network you are transmitting over (e.g. 1388 bytes for IPv4/Ethernet).  Very small packet-sizes (like 48-bytes/packet) are inefficient, since the fixed-sized packet-headers make up a greater percentage of the total data sent/received.
- Only try to send when your sending-socket indicates it is ready-for-write.  (i.e. don't assume that you will never fill up the socket's outgoing-data-buffer; if your traffic is "bursty", you probably will at some point)
- Minimize UDP packet loss by making your UDP sockets' send and receive buffers as large as you can get away with
- Further minimize UDP packet loss by doing all the UDP receiving in a dedicated, high-priority thread (which can then route the received UDP data back to a normal-priority thread for further processing -- the main thing is to avoid allowing the receiving UDP-socket's incoming-data-buffer to overflow if possible)
- For the TCP retransmission part, keep in mind that TCP streams can potentially slow down to nearly zero bytes-per-second in the worst case scenario, which makes it important to ensure that poor TCP performance to client A doesn't block the TCP communications to/from clients B, C, D, etc.  This can be accomplished either via non-blocking I/O and `select()` (or `poll()` or similar), or asynchronous networking, or via multiple threads; avoid blocking I/O unless you are implementing a thread-per-socket model (and probably avoid that model as well, since a thread that is indefinitely-blocked-inside-recv() is difficult to shut down cleanly)
- Think about under what circumstances (if any) it is acceptable for a client to never receive a particular packet at all; are there situations where that is okay?  Or must the entire system grind to a halt until every receiver has received every packet in the group, regardless of how long that might take?
- If you want to get really fancy, you can look into [Forward Error Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) algorithms that encode data across packets, such that the receiver can still decode all of the data even if it never receives (up to a certain percentage of) the packets.  This makes the need for a re-transmit request less likely, at the cost of making all of the packets slightly larger.

Comment: I get the udp multicast part, but why resend data via tcp? Wouldn't multicast udp once again (or udp directly targeted at the one comp, that missed data) be better? I mean you either open tcp for every packet, which is like 8+ udp packets per transmition (so you must have low drop udp ratio, or it won't fly at all), or you keep tcp opened for every destination, in which case u need to invent your own over tcp protocol, which is annoying and can go wrong in so many ways.

Comment: @ Radoslaw Cybulski ... The sender is the Stock Exchange. I can't ask sender to change their protocol. This means sender sends the retransmits on TCP only, while UDP stream is used for sending the live data. The UDP drop ratio is very small ( less than 0.001%) except when starting the UDP multicast in the middle of the day, in which case all previously sent UDP packets from 1 to some N will need to be resent on TCP, while UDP takes over live streaming transmission from N+1 onward.